# Image over UITableVIew Cell upon selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I want to display an image over a cell upon selection. I've tried endless ways to do so without succes. 
I've tried adding this to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"deselected_image.png"];
cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image.png"];
```

But the image won't change upon push.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is creating a new table view cell - you need to retrieve the current cell that was selected.  Try the following instead:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"deselected_image.png"];
    cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image.png"];
```

}

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I can comment out the line starting with `cell.imageView.highlightedImage` and it won't change anything. The other line,  When I push the cell the image appears only after I release my finger. I want it to show up instantly.

Comment: I managed to get it kinda work but the image doesn't remove it self when leaving the VC. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the UIColor to each cell on request.You can replace the UIColor code & apply the image.
Here is my code

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if(tableView==tblLanguage)
    {
           cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];

          ((UIView *)cell.backgroundView).backgroundColor = !(indexPath.row % 2)?[UIColor colorWithRed:(float)231/255 green:(float)231/255 blue:(float)231/255 alpha:1.0]:[UIColor colorWithRed:(float)218/255 green:(float)218/255 blue:(float)218/255 alpha:1.0];
          ((UIView *)cell.backgroundView).alpha=1.0;
    //ilangSelectedIndex is set in the didselect row of the tableview delegate function
     if(ilangSelectedIndex==[indexPath row])
      {
            ((UIView *)cell.backgroundView).backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(float)171/255 green:(float)177/255 blue:(float)213/255 alpha:1.0];       
       }
            cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     }


}
```

In the Did select function of the table you **set the ilangSelectedIndex as Indexpath.row** of your table & **reload the table** to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.selectedBackgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
cell.backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
```